# How to add sb-admin-2 in jhipster

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jhipster

I would like create web application use of jhipster with sb-admin-2 (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/). How to add easily and fast sb-admin-2 templae to jhipster ?
I would like to make my application look like as JHipster - home page: http://jhipster.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can install this template with:

```
bower install startbootstrap-sb-admin-2
```

After the installation you need to adapt the html and css code.

If you need some hints the source code from http://jhipster.github.io/ is available on [Github](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io) .